# Complexity analysis exercise on RB-Trees

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence, red-black-tree

```
BLACK_PATH(T,x)
 if x==NIL 
    then return TRUE
 if COLOR(x)==BLACK
    then return BLACK_PATH(T,left(x)) || BLACK_PATH(T,right(x))
 return FALSE
```

The exercises asks to analyse the complexity of this procedure. I believe the reccurrence is the following

T(n)<=2T(2n/3)+O(1)

Using the recursion tree I obtain T(n)=O(n). Is this correct?

Comment: Why `2n/3`? Not saying it is wrong I just am not sure how you derived that.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov But it appears, to me at least, that each recursive call is on average half of `n`. That leads me to believe that this operation is at the very worst case linear (`O(n)`), since in the very worst case every element is "touched" once. But this would only happen if every element was black.

Comment: @GarrettGutierrez 2n/3 based on analysis I read about Heaps in which the subtree has at max 2n/3 nodes (with n the length of the array). But in this case you are probably right: the sub tree has at max n/2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of this method is linear (`O(n)`) in the worst case with regards to the number of elements in the tree.

Using the master theorem in terms of the total number of nodes here is difficult because it does not take into account the properties of a red black tree. While it is true in general for heaps that every subtree of a tree with `n` nodes has max `2n/3` nodes, it is also true that for red black trees every subtree has at max `n/2` **black** nodes. This is because red black trees are balanced with respect to black nodes (every path downwards to a leaf node from an arbitrary node has the same number of black nodes).

Most importantly: because the number of total nodes is not asymptotically higher than the number of black nodes you can, by analyzing the complexity purely with regards to the total number of black nodes, implicitly analyze the complexity with regards to the total number of nodes.

So rather than using `T(n)<=2T(2n/3)+O(1)` you should use `T(m)<=T(m/2)+O(1)` where `m` is the number of black nodes which gives you `O(m)` and because, as previously discussed, `O(m)==O(n)`, we have `O(n)`.

Another way to think about it: So long as you can understand that this algorithm is `O(n)` when all the nodes in the tree are black, you should be able to understand that it could only possibly require fewer operations if some of the nodes in the tree are red, since regardless of where the red node is every node in the subtree rooted at that red node will be ignored and not visited by this recursive algorithm. So it can only be `O(n)` or better, establishing `O(n)` as your worst case.

Comment: But if the entire tree is black, the procedure only examines log2 n nodes, assuming that `||` is short-circuiting.

Comment: I think the worst case has all the leaves red and the rest of the nodes black, in which case all the nodes will be examined. So your analysis is fine.